# windows update does not take place at WINDOWS 7/64/SP 1

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a genuine Windows 7 Sp1.

I've formatted my laptop. When I run Windows Update it checks for updates, but no update is downloaded.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you look at the Windows update log (`Windowsupdate.log`) as shown on Microsoft's support site ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093 ) and are you really sure that there are still updates that should be downloaded (not an obvious thing to be sure of!)?

Comment: "I've formatted my laptop" - does it mean you've reinstalled Windows? Weren't any updates downloaded since that time, or it just stopped at a time? Is your windows activated?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur if one or more of the following conditions are true:

- The Windows Update database is corrupted.
- Antivirus software is configured to scan the %Windir%\SoftwareDistribution folder.
- The Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) service does not receive a content link header.
- A required system file is registered incorrectly.
- Windows Installer encountered an error.
- The Component Based Servicing (CBS) manifest is corrupted.
- The Windows Update service stops during the installation process.
- There's a file version conflict with Windows Update agent files.

To resolve this problem, try each of the following methods. After each method, test to see whether the problem is resolved before you go on to the next method. **If the problem is resolved by any method, you don't have to try the remaining methods.**

Method 1: Run the Windows Update troubleshooter

[Windows Update troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262)

Method 2: Download and manually install the update

To do this, follow these steps:

Determine the Microsoft Knowledge Base article number of the failed update.

To do this, do one of the following:

View the error code message.

View the update history on the Windows Update website or on the Microsoft Update website.

To do this, follow these steps:

Go to the following Microsoft Update website:
http://update.microsoft.com

Under Options, click Review your update history.

In the Update column, determine the Microsoft Knowledge Base article number of the failed update.

For more details refer this [Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2509997)